# Add IdentityUser to HttpContext.User

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using .NET Core 3.0 . I am trying to authenticate a user via an API Key authorization. I have created a middleware that is called every time a controller endpoint is called. I can authenticate the user and get the claims but I cannot set the `HttpContext.User` object to use this identity.

```cs
   public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Invoke(HttpContext context, Services.AuthenticationService authenticationService, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager)
        {
            if (!context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("Token") && context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/api")))
            {
                var userKey = context.Request.Headers["user-key"];

                 // Register the user and its claims to the session
                var user = authenticationService.GetUserFromToken(userKey);
                var claims = await userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);

                if (claims == null)
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 401; //UnAuthorized
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Claims not found for user");
                    return;
                }

                var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
                claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id));
                claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));
                claimsIdentity.AddClaims(claims);
                context.User.AddIdentity(claimsIdentity);
                await _signInManager.Context.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));
            }

            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
```

When I check `HttpContext.User` in my controller the main identity object has no information. In the Identities object there are two identies. The second identity has the the claim and user name that I set in the middleware.

How do I set the main identity to be the one and only identity? The `_signInManager` code doesn't actually do anything and I get the same results in the `HttpContext.User` object with or without it.

Comment: In my opinion, if you have checked the token is valid, there is no need to call the SignInAsync again in your middleware, you could directly set the claims like below:               `var claims = new List<Claim> { /* add claims */ };`
            `var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, ClaimTypes.Name);`
         `context.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);`

Comment: Ok, so it was as simple as just setting context.User = to the claims principal. For some reason I didn't expect that to be a settable.
 
Thanks for this. I cannot accept your comment as the answer though.